# import error in python ::> I am trying to import operations.py file in nearest_neighbor.py

Tags: python, virtual-environment

I am using python virtual environment

Tried many import statement but nothing is working

```
from . import operations
```

Get this:

```
error: ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Also tried this

```
from ML_algorithms_learning.nearest_neighbor import operations
```

Then get this:

```
error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ML_algorithms_learning'
```

sys.path:

```
 ['f:\portfolio\Website\ML_algorithms_learning\nearest_neighbor', 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python39.zip', 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\DLLs', 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib', 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39', 'F:\portfolio\Website\Scripts', 'F:\portfolio\Website\Scripts\lib\site-packages']
```

Folder Structure:

[image: Folder structure]

Though import statement worked when I tried to import it from root of the environment

```
 [code] : https://i.stack.imgur.com/scUAn.png
```

Output:

[image]

Python.exe path:

[image]

Comment: In which file are you importing the module `ML_algorithms...`?

Comment: Before `from . import operations`, please do `import os` and `print(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))` and show what you get.

Comment: Also to help this get answered faster, please delete the discussion with PCM which does not contribute.

Comment: Also, be careful with file names starting with `test`, as you will get name clashes with certain libraries such as `pytest`.

Comment: thanks, I have found the solution and fixed it